# Jackson - Object Not Saved as Basic JSON when using type JsonNode

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

I'm using Spring Boot (Kotlin) and Mongo to save some data into my DB.

I have Mongo's collection defined like so:

```
@Document(collection = "events")
data class Event(
    val id: String,
    val payload: JsonNode
)
```

Then when I got to save it I'm using: `objectMapper.convertValue(it.payload)`

However what I see in the DB is a little odd, its like its some sort of actual memory representation, when I all want are simple key and values:

```
"payload": {
        "_children": {
            "title": {
                "_children": {
                    "value": {
                        "_value": "Solutions green",
                        "_class": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode"
                    }
                },
                "_nodeFactory": {
                    "_cfgBigDecimalExact": false
                },
                "_class": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode"
            },
            "description": {
                "_value": "Earum et debitis officiis porro distinctio quasi et.",
                "_class": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode"
            },
```

That payload can contain anything, so generic Json hence using JsonNode.

What is that being inserted above and how do I actually just save the basic json representation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like this because Mongo internally uses something other than `Jackson` and do not recognize `JsonNode`. Probably you need to convert it manually to string calling `payload.toString` somewhere or somehow configure `Mongo` and provide `JsonNode` custom serialisation

Comment: Hi, Thanks but I'm still a little unsure about what I need to do here

Comment: I ended up using `val payload: Object` and everything worked as needed. Not sure though what the difference was - i guess Object can be deserialized fine by Mongo. In that case why would JsonNode ever be used?

Comment: When you use `Object`, `Jackson` picks for `JSON Object` `Map` instance and for `JSON Array` - `List` instance. You can use `JsonNode` when you want to traverse node and find specific value, it has better `API` than `Map` and supports `JSON Pointer`. With `Map` and `List` - Mongo's `JSON` serialiser does not have any problem this why it works for you. `payload.toString` was needed to generate pure `JSON` representation without internal `JsonNode` attributes which we would like to skip.

Comment: Ah ok - so you mean to say `objectMapper.convertValue(it.payload.toString())` should work when using `payload: JsonNode`?

Comment: related?: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/2557